# M1 Macbook Air crash on running 4 simple C process in parallel

Tags: hardware, crash, apple-silicon, apple-hardware-test

I have started reading Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces, when I ran the example 2.1 on my MacBook Air M1 with 4 instances in parallel it spawned 4 unique processes but then my laptop crashed after 2-3 seconds. Please find the steps to replicate below:

`simple-example.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "common.h"
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]){
if (argc != 2) {
fprintf(stderr, "usage: cpu <string>\n"); exit(1);
    }
    char *str = argv[1]; 
    while (1) {
Spin(1);
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
return 0; }
```

`[common.h][1]`

```
#ifndef __common_h__
#define __common_h__

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <assert.h>

double GetTime() {
    struct timeval t;
    int rc = gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    assert(rc == 0);
    return (double) t.tv_sec + (double) t.tv_usec/1e6;
}

void Spin(int howlong) {
    double t = GetTime();
    while ((GetTime() - t) < (double) howlong)
    ; // do nothing in loop
}

#endif // __common_h__
```

The program above as explained by the book:

> Figure 2.1 depicts our first program. It doesn’t do much. In fact, all it does is call Spin(), a function that repeatedly checks the time and returns once it has run for a second. Then, it prints out the string that the user passed in on the command line, and repeats, forever.

I have copied common.h from the linked github file

Compile:

```
~ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

```
gcc -o cpu simple-example.c -Wall
```

running a single instance of the process with a string works fine:

```
./cpu "A"
```

running multiple instances crashes the laptop:

```
./cpu A & ; ./cpu B & ; ./cpu C & ; ./cpu D &
```

This spawns 4 processes and starts printing the strings A C B D in random order but then a purple light flashed and the laptop died.

Laptop Specification:

```
OS: Big Sur
Version: 11.5.2
Chip: M1
Memory: 8GB
```

Crash Report:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffe002fb3f460): "Spinlock timeout after 12584284 ticks, 0xfffffe0033898588 = fffffe1667d2dfe1"
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0xff
OS release type: User
OS version: 20G95
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Wed Jun 23 00:26:27 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.2~5/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: 15F4DFDFA9E0154FED96EA8997E65429
Kernel UUID: AC4A14A7-8A8E-3AE6-85A6-55E6B2502BF9
iBoot version: iBoot-6723.140.2
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000027ec4000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe002eec8000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000028a0c000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe002fa10000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe002fadc000
mach_absolute_time: 0xac2324506
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x613ff694 0x00019680
  Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x613ffe14 0x00092243

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fc4d6a4
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fc4ed6c
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fc4ed6c
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fc4ed6c
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fc4ed70
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fc4ed70
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fc4ed70
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fc4ed70
CORE 0 PVH locks held: None
CORE 1 PVH locks held: None
CORE 2 PVH locks held: None
CORE 3 PVH locks held: None
CORE 4 PVH locks held: None
CORE 5 PVH locks held: None
CORE 6 PVH locks held: None
CORE 7 PVH locks held: None
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0xfffffe002faecc28, LR=0xfffffe002faecc28, FP=0x0000000000000000
CORE 2: PC=0xfffffe002fb251f0, LR=0xfffffe002fb251f0, FP=0xfffffe3f58b4bd50
CORE 3: PC=0xfffffe002faecc28, LR=0xfffffe002faecc28, FP=0x0000000000000000
CORE 4: PC=0xfffffe002fb25200, LR=0xfffffe003004f268, FP=0xfffffe30987c3db0
CORE 5: PC=0xfffffe002fb25200, LR=0xfffffe003004f268, FP=0xfffffe309b17bdb0
CORE 6: PC=0xfffffe002fb25200, LR=0xfffffe003004f268, FP=0xfffffe3f5966bdb0
CORE 7: PC=0xfffffe002fb25200, LR=0xfffffe003004f268, FP=0xfffffe309af7bdb0
Panicked task 0xfffffe167984a1f8: 100 pages, 4 threads: pid 778: redis-server
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe16797df300, backtrace: 0xfffffe3f5958b6d0, tid: 6902
          lr: 0xfffffe002fb2ab68  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958b740
          lr: 0xfffffe002fb2a94c  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958b7b0
          lr: 0xfffffe002fc541c8  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958b7d0
          lr: 0xfffffe002fc45674  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958b880
          lr: 0xfffffe002fae37e8  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958b890
          lr: 0xfffffe002fb2a5dc  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958bc20
          lr: 0xfffffe002fb2a5dc  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958bc90
          lr: 0xfffffe00302dce80  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958bcb0
          lr: 0xfffffe002fb3f460  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958bce0
          lr: 0xfffffe002fb3f2cc  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958bd00
          lr: 0xfffffe002fb25174  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958bd50
          lr: 0xfffffe003004f268  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958bdb0
          lr: 0xfffffe00301320e8  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958be40
          lr: 0xfffffe002fc45350  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958bef0
          lr: 0xfffffe002fae37e8  fp: 0xfffffe3f5958bf00

last started kext at 697335366: com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0 (addr 0xfffffe002f988000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 4050.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  1677.141.1
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   11.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  556.100.11
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.driver.AppleDPDisplayTCON 1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L83Audio  442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp   442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103CLPCv3   1
com.apple.AGXG13G   173.28.7
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   385
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  401.73.4
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    4.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP    140.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostT8103  1
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8103   1.60.5
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XWatchDogTimer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8101 1
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI    1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   1
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   311
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    4440.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   224
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  4440.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 4050.1
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 940.4
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   985.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory  1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHostControllerPCIeTransport 8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  16.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransportSPI   4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    4400.35
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy    173.28.7
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  173.28.7
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 442.26
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    80.34.1
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 21.11
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   4.75.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH13CameraInterface    3.58.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH10PearlCameraInterface   16.15.1
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIARM    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.watchdog   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.2
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211FamilyV2 1200.12.2b1
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8103    540.10
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    985.2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    585.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothPacketLogger 8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  68.7.1
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    511.141.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  184.140.2
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   436.140.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   436.140.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 1.17
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   290.8.1
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  3.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    11.1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 364005 (Uncompressed 950640) **
```

This is happened both the times I run the code, Geekbench 5 is running fine [result](https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/9822184)

Is this some problem with code or M1 SOC issue?

How do I explain this to apple to get a replacement? I bought this laptop on August 4th without apple care

Update: @DarkDust suggested killing redis and trying, still crashing.

Comment: `Spinlock timeout…` and `Panicked task … pid 778: redis-server`  This looks like an OS issue. You're overwhelming the system, another task is (indirectly?) using a kernel spin lock and that is held for too long. You may want to report this to Apple using Feedback.

Comment: Should I expect this to happen with every MacBook Air m1? or is this laptop specific issue?

Comment: You should not expect this to happen, it's a bug (IMHO). An OS bug.

Comment: It's happening every time I run this code for me

Comment: Great! Then report it to Apple if you can reproduce it every time. For example, via https://www.apple.com/feedback/

Comment: The process that is crashing is not your process but redis-server which is not part of macOS. Turn redis off and try again.

Comment: However digging through the book and its reference to this  [stack exchnage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897963/documented-way-to-disable-aslr-on-os-x) It uses an undocumented flag and not SO I expect Apple would say don't use it. (For playing woth OS type things I would install Linux in a virtual machine as you will crash things)

Comment: I have stopped redis and then tried, it is still crashing!

Comment: What is the panniced task now - and does it still crash if you remove the undocumented flag

Comment: @mmmmmm Which undocumented flag are you referring to?

Comment: @mmmmmm will crash my machine again as soon as possibleble and get the logs to see what panics the processor

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal Can you add the output of `gcc -v` to your question so we can tell what toolchain you're building with?

Comment: Also, can you add the `keepsyms=1` argument to your `boot-args` NVRAM variable and reboot so that we can see a symbolicated backtrace in your panic report? (Let me know if you need instructions)

Comment: @pion added `gcc -v` output will add the `keepsyms` arg and try as soon as I get time.

Comment: What happens when you change optimization level and re-run the recompiled binary? E.g., add `-O3` to your `gcc` args. (Make sure that this changes the byte count of the binary, i.e., run `stat -f "%z" cpu` and make sure the number changed from before vs. after. Try different optimizations levels 0/1/2/3)

Comment: my only question is, is it safe to crash my laptop these many times?

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal Yes, this particular crash is safe to repeat (just first make sure that all your open documents have been saved and you also invoke `sync` to force a flush of memory-mapped files to disk, prior to inducing the panic). There is likely a race condition somewhere in the kernel and we are trying to gather more information on the root cause, which requires repeatedly trying to reproduce the crash while changing one variable at a time.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal, this crashes on my M1 MBA as well (Mac OS 11.4). Runs for a couple seconds before everything goes unresponsive and crashes with the purple screen.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried on an M1 Mini, it already crashes with three processes, without printing any letter at all.

```
./cpu A & ./cpu B & ./cpu C &
```

Best to report it to Apple then.

Comment: It's not happening to everyone, /u/BadWulfy on Reddit tried the same and was able to run the program without any crashes! [Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/macbook/comments/pntnk4/macbook_air_m1_crashes_on_running_simple_c/hct3967/)

Comment: I assumed that the user would use an M1, anyway I have asked to confirm his SOC.

Comment: The use confirmed they have a M1 Macbook Air

Comment: can you add your crash logs here so that we can compare them to mine, it would be really helpfull

Comment: When your machine crashes you get a "your computer restarted because of a problem" dialog after it reboots chose send a report and then copy that report and add it here.  If possible please run the code again and get the report. Thanks in Advance